# IPhone Decryption with private key -Data Encrypted in Java

Tags: iphone, rsa, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

Can anyone help with the code how to decrypt with private key ,As in server side they are using OAEP encryption method .I tried decrypting using private key but the decrypted text is Null,I am getting the Error code as -9809 as decryption code result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "with a private key" I assume you mean you're using `SecKeyDecrypt()` for asymmetric encryption rather than CommonCryptor for symmetric encryption.

`SecKeyDecrypt()` does not support OAEP. It only supports PKCS1 v1.5 padding (`kSecPaddingPKCS1`). It can also technically handle ASN.1 padding + PKCS1 padding, but this isn't usually relevant to decryption. You should have noticed this when you passed the SecPadding parameter. What did you pass?

That error number is `errSSLCrypto` which is a generic "something went wrong in crypto" message.